# Java Unity error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm new to java and trying to get some sample code running. I get the following error

It says ";" expected, insert ; insert semicolon at the end for each of the variables

I'm wondering how I could fix this problem and get the code running, thanks!

```
#pragma strict
import UnityEngine;
import System.Collections;

public class Move 
{

    //A method that Unity uses to re-run the code every second
    function Update ()
    {
        double moveTime;
        double currentMoveTime;
        double perc = 1;
        //if the input is given from an android
        if ((Input.GetButtonDown("left") || Input.GetButtonDown("right") || Input.GetButtonDown("center")))
        {
            if (perc == 1)
            {
                moveTime = 1;
                currentMoveTime = 0;
            }
        }
        //Adjusting position
        startPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        if(((Input.GetButtonDown("right") && gameObject.transform.position == endPos)))
        {
            endPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.x);
        }
        if((Input.GetButtonDown("left") && gameObject.transform.position == endPos))
        {
            endPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1,  transform.position.y, transform.position.x);
        }
        if((Input.GetButtonDown("center") && gameObject.transform.position == endPos))
        {
            endPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x,  transform.position.y, transform.position.x);
        }
        //Speed up move time after enough time passes
        currentMoveTime += Time.deltaTime * 5.5;
        perc = currentMoveTime / moveTime;
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, perc);
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw the first line: `#pragma strict` what is this? Is this in your code?
Also this is not a java code: `function Update ()` java does not have keyword `function`

Comment: You are mixing C# and Unityscript/Javascript. Please use one. I suggest you learn C#. You can start [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting)

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can't use Java in Unity.
 What you see is C#
```

Comment: No, this is *not* C#, it's (mostly) UnityScript / Javascript.